# Transfer file from one cloud storage to another

Tags: onedrive, cloud-storage

I'm wondering if it's possible to transfer files from one cloud storage to another "on the fly"? Specifically I want to build an app that will transfer my photos from Skydrive to Box.net without saving files temporarily to my databases, but saving files directly to Box.net storage?

Thanks,
Lojza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any cloud provider that provides an API for transferring data to a competing cloud provider, but I'm not familiar with skydrive or box.net.  Cloud providers have no incentive to help you move your data to the competition.  You will almost certainly have to read the data to your local machine then write it to Box.net

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with https://app.mover.io/ and http://otixo.com/
These are just for this purpose..